# In Nginx why might 405 error page display properly in the main server block but not in server blocks that redirect to the main block?

Tags: nginx

I use two server blocks to forward all requests to a main block that serves all requests with a `https://www` prefix.  When I throw a 405 error with `https://www` in the request the corresponding error page is displayed as expected.

However when I use an `http` or `https` only prefix and use Postman to send a DELETE or PATCH request the request goes through one of the first 2 server blocks and no error is returned. The page is displayed normally as if a GET request had been made.

How do I alter my config so that errors are displayed regardless of the request's prefix?

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:1m rate=50r/s;
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;

    sendfile      on;
    tcp_nopush    on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    gzip_vary on;

    server_tokens off;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844];

    error_page 400 /html/400.html;
    error_page 403 /html/403.html;
    error_page 404 /html/404.html;
    error_page 405 /html/405.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /html/50x.html;

    server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

    }

    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

    }


    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

        root /srv/example/views/public;

        location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp|ico)$ {
            valid_referers none blocked server_names ~\.bing\. ~\.duckduckgo\. ~\.facebook\. ~\.google\. ~\.instagram\. ~\.twitter\. ~\.yahoo\.;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return 403;
            }
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self';";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=31536000";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location ~* \.(css)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location ~* \.(htm|html)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; media-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://js.stripe.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header feature-policy "autoplay 'none'; legacy-image-formats 'none'; oversized-images 'none'; unsized-media 'none';";
            add_header permissions-policy "autoplay=(); legacy-image-formats=(); oversized-images=(); unsized-media=();";
            add_header referrer-policy strict-origin;
            add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31557600; includesubdomains";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
            add_header x-frame-options sameorigin;
        }

        location ~* \.(js)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self';";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location / {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; media-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://js.stripe.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header feature-policy "autoplay 'none'; legacy-image-formats 'none'; oversized-images 'none'; unsized-media 'none';";
            add_header permissions-policy "autoplay=(); legacy-image-formats=(); oversized-images=(); unsized-media=();";
            add_header referrer-policy strict-origin;
            add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31557600; includesubdomains";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
            add_header x-frame-options sameorigin;
            proxy_hide_header x-powered-by;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name testbed.example.com;

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        return 301 https://testbed.example.com$request_uri;

    }

    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name testbed.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testbed.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testbed.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testbed.example.com/chain.pem;

        root /srv/testbed/views/public;

        location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp|ico)$ {
            valid_referers none blocked server_names ~\.bing\. ~\.duckduckgo\. ~\.facebook\. ~\.google\. ~\.instagram\. ~\.twitter\. ~\.yahoo\.;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return 403;
            }
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self';";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=31536000";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location ~* \.(css)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location ~* \.(htm|html)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; media-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://js.stripe.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header feature-policy "autoplay 'none'; legacy-image-formats 'none'; oversized-images 'none'; unsized-media 'none';";
            add_header permissions-policy "autoplay=(); legacy-image-formats=(); oversized-images=(); unsized-media=();";
            add_header referrer-policy strict-origin;
            add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31557600; includesubdomains";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
            add_header x-frame-options sameorigin;
        }

        location ~* \.(js)$ {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self';";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
        }

        location / {
            add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; media-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://js.stripe.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;";
            add_header cache-control "public, max-age=2629746";
            add_header feature-policy "autoplay 'none'; legacy-image-formats 'none'; oversized-images 'none'; unsized-media 'none';";
            add_header permissions-policy "autoplay=(); legacy-image-formats=(); oversized-images=(); unsized-media=();";
            add_header referrer-policy strict-origin;
            add_header strict-transport-security "max-age=31557600; includesubdomains";
            add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
            add_header x-frame-options sameorigin;
            proxy_hide_header x-powered-by;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10001;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Your first two blocks send redirects. Did you omit some part of the configuration?

Comment: Hm, I think you need to put the `return 301` inside a `location /` block.

Comment: Why would you be scared to do that? It should have absolutely no effect on anything else, unless of course there is _still_ configuration you haven't shared...

Comment: Yeah, then definitely share the rest of the configuration.

Comment: Where are the contents of the include files?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) tells the following:

> The specified condition is evaluated. If true, this module directives specified inside the braces are executed, and the request is assigned the configuration inside the if directive. Configurations inside the if directives are inherited from the previous configuration level.

In your example configuration, this would mean that the `return 301` configuration is inherited from the parent configuration level. The documentation doesn't tell what happens when previous configuration level and current level both contain a `return` directive. But from your result, it seems that the inherited directive is preserved.

It was already suggested that the redirect would be included inside a location. I am writing an exact configuration here to highlight how the config block should look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 405;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use `limit_except`. This is an untested version:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /
        error_page 403 =405 /html/405.html;
        limit_except GET POST {
            deny all;
        }

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

`limit_except` allows GET and POST methods, all others are denied. HEAD is allowed implicitly by allowing GET.

`error_page` directive is used to translate `403` error code from `deny all` to `405` return code and to display the error page.